# Testing rake tasks with rspec doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, rakefile

I'm trying to test a very simple rake task with rspec, but I'm finding it very difficult and whatever change I do my tests don't seem to fail...

This is the task I'm trying to test:

```
desc 'Outputs the current version of Rivendell'
task version: :environment do
  puts Rivendell::VERSION
end
```

As you can see, it's a very basic task.

This is my test:

```
describe 'Rakefile' do
  before :each do
    Rake.application.rake_require File.expand_path(
      '../../Rakefile', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    Rake::Task.define_task :environment    
  end

  describe 'rivendell::version' do
    let :run_rake_task do
      Rake::Task["rivendell::version"].reenable
    Rake.application.invoke_task "rivendell::version"
  end
  it 'should display the right version' do
    Rivendell.should_receive('VERSION')
    run_rake_task
  end
end
```

All tests for some reason pass, but if I change the should_receive call to

```
Rivendell.should_receive('DOESNTEXIST')
```

All tests pass in any case.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Rivendell.should_receive('DOESNTEXIST')` what is this?

Comment: A random call to prove the spec is not really working. It should fail because Rivendell never received a DOESNTEXIST call.

Comment: Try Fantaskspec - https://github.com/crismali/fantaskspec